# Flutter Error: _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Database>')

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Opening the sqlite database in assets folder. but I get this error.
I tried ' return _db ?? = await initDb(); ' but it's not work.
i don't understand why i got this error..
please help me..

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:bankingapp/models/histories.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DbHelper {
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    return _db = await initDb(); // <-- error is here
  }

  initDb() async {
    var dbDir = await getDatabasesPath();
    var dbPath = join(dbDir, "app.db");

// Delete any existing database:
    await deleteDatabase(dbPath);

// Create the writable database file from the bundled demo database file:
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/database/bankingapp.db");
    List<int> bytes =
        data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);

    var db = await openDatabase(dbPath);

    /*
    var dbFolder = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(dbFolder, 'app.db');
    
    return await openDatabase(path);*/
  }

  Future<List<Histories>> getHistories() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Histories");
    return result.map((data) => Histories.fromMap(data)).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445470/how-to-fix-type-type-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-futureorverse-in-flutter)?

Comment: yes but I don't understand anything :/

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.

```
Future<Database> initDb() async {
    var dbFolder = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(dbFolder, 'app.db');

    // Delete any existing database:
    await deleteDatabase(path);

    // Create the writable database file from the bundled demo database file:
    try {
      await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
    } catch (_) {}
    ByteData data =
        await rootBundle.load(join("assets/database", "bankingapp.db"));
    List<int> bytes =
        data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);

    //open the database
    return await openDatabase(path);

  }
```